# Desencriptado con libreria Encrypt de Codeigniter no devuelve el resultado correcto

Tags: php, codeigniter

estoy teniendo unos problemas con la libreria encrypt de codeigniter
Tengo alojado en mi base de datos una serie de campos con datos encriptados

```
        $serie1=$this->encrypt->encode("i_dsk");
```

El la linea de codigo de arriba  es como guardo mis variables (encriptadas) para despues enviarlas por array a una consulta, los datos se encriptan y guardan correctamente sin ningún problema
Ya tengo en el archivo config.php la clave de encriptado, incluso he utilizado una llave alternativa para encriptar y desencriptar, pero sigo sin tener el mismo resultado.

Lo primero que hago es hacer una consulta a la bd,(Codigo de mi modelo)

```
public function consulta_datos_para_hacer_licencia($correo){
                 $this->db->select('dato1');
                 $this->db->where('lic_correo',$correo);
                 $result_query=$this->db->get('user_data');
                 return $result_query->result_array();
             }
```

Ahora en el controlador trato de acceder a solo uno de los campos que requiero, por ejemplo **dato1**.

```
        $query_result=$this->user_model->consulta_datos_para_hacer_licencia($correo_us_mail);//Obtengo en el controller el dato en un array
    $dato1=$this->encrypt->decode($query_result[0]{"dato"}); //Accedo al campo dato1 tratando de hacer el desencriptado
```

Pero al momento de pintar el resultado solo me indica el nombre del campo, es decir "dato1" , al principio creí que era error mio al tratar de acceder al array, pero hice el mismo ejemplo pero sin desencriptar y me indico el valor del campo de "dato1" por ejemplo me muestra "JSDKV/=IJSDI", pero lo que necesito es el dato sin el encriptado que en su caso seria "hola".

De antemano muchas gracias por el apoyo, estoy atorado con este inconveniente desde ayer

Comment: Saludos. Disculpa mi comentario; CodeIgniter no lo he usado; pero el proceso de cifrar y descifrar siempre es el mismo; observo que tienes `$this->encrypt->decode($query_result[0]{"dato"});` no veo la referencia que pones de la libreria o lo que usas para cifrar/descifrar pero en creo debe ser `...->decrypter(...);` ( ver https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html ); más sin embargo en url https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encrypt.html veo algo como lo que usas pero hay que pasar la llave; por lo visto es un algoritmo de llave simetrica.

Comment: Claro, entiendo, agregue anteriormente una llave diferente almacenada en una variable, y en base a la documentación agregue esa llave despues del campo que debo encriptar, aun así cuando guardo el dato encriptado y vuelvo a consultar, y trato de desencriptarlo con la misma llave, me da otro resultado

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, no puedo creer que no había notado mi horrible error.

```
$serie1=$this->encrypt->encode("i_dsk");
```

Estoy encriptado la cadena "i_dsk", y no el campo que estoy recibiendo del input. Es por eso que cada que trataba de hacer el desencriptado me salia el mismo resultado.